# How to call a method from a different class

Tags: c#, .net, windows

At the moment I have created a new method in a new class, and I am trying to call this method from my main class:

Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testing();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and the method is in "Class1.cs":

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2

    {
        class Class1
        {

            public static void testing()
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("It works!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `Class1.testing()` ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the name of the class that the method is on. So:

```
Class1.testing();
```

Sometimes you might of course need to also worry about the namespace that Class1 is in. In this case both Class1 and Main are in the same namespace. If they hadn't been though then you'd have had to call it like:

```
ConsoleApplication2.DifferentNamespace.Class1.testing();
```

or with a using declaration at the top of program.cs:

```
using ConsoleApplication2.DifferentNamespace
```

Answer (score 2):

You have made testing a static method, so you can call the method in this fashion

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Class1.testing();
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `class` declaration in order to use the `static` method:

`Class1.testing();`

Comment: These look like good answers. Maybe you should mark the one that helped you the most as "accepted"?

Answer (score 0):

Class 1 has to be a public class and then you can call `Class1.testing()`